# Why am I getting CURLE_NOT_BUILT_IN when using libcurl with CURLOPT_PROXY?

Tags: c++, libcurl, burp

I'm debugging some HTTP request, using a proxy (Burp).

Let's say we have this command, running OK. *Burp is capturing everything*:

```
curl --proxy localhost:8080 -k https://www.ipchicken.com/
```

Now I'm trying to do the same, programmatically:

```
CURL     *curlHandle;
CURLcode curlErrorCode;
curlHandle=curl_easy_init();
curlErrorCode=curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.ipchicken.com/");
curlErrorCode=curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle,CURLOPT_PROXY,"https://127.0.0.1:8080");
curlErrorCode=curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curlErrorCode=curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle,CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1L);
// ...
curlErrorCode=curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);
// ...
curl_easy_cleanup(curlHandle);
```

All the curl_easy_setopt() calls return CURLE_OK. But curl_easy_perform() is returning CURLE_NOT_BUILT_IN.

This does not make sense, since the curl executable was made in the same build as the library I'm using.

Any idea about what could be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace https:// with http:// for the *CURLOPT_PROXY* option:

```
curlErrorCode=curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle,CURLOPT_PROXY,"http://127.0.0.1:8080");
```

It works now.

For the record, even building libcurl with *all features/packages* did not allow me to use HTTPS for the proxy type.

Comment: then you use a too old curl version or a TLS backend that doesn't support HTTPS proxy