# Application fails to launch via Visual Studio 2003 - CURLE_NOT_BUILT_IN Curl error displayed in debugger

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, libcurl, c++98

We have a legacy MFC based application in our company which is built with Visual C++98 on Visual Studio 2003. We use curl for Http requests. libcurl.lib file is linked into the project.
I see 2 behaviors while executing the HTTP requests.

1. When we launch the application from Visual studio or the bin folder directly, I get an `CURLE_NOT_BUILT_IN` error and the application refuses to proceed further.
2. When the application is packaged and installed in another folder via an installer, the application runs perfectly fine. 0 issues whatsoever.

Can anyone help me understand why the application fails to launch via the Visual studio?

Note: libcurl.lib file has been in the repository since ages. Also, this issue propped up recently. It was working fine 2 weeks ago and affects only my computer.

Comment: Perhaps a similar issue to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65259843/why-am-i-getting-curle-not-built-in-when-using-libcurl-with-curlopt-proxy)? The `http` versus `https` issue I mean.

Comment: Umm no, it works fine when application is installed elsewhere. And it was working fine in Visual studio until it was not. So I am not able to debug my application now

Comment: my guess would be that there's another libcurl dll/library somewhere on your machine which is being used instead of the one you're expecting

Comment: Now comes the hard part: Remembering what you did about two weeks ago. Things like this doesn't just happen, there's always some change being made that lead to them. Someone did something, and that stopped libcurl from working. If it was a code change and you have a VCS (Version Control System, like Git or Subversion or similar) you can rollback code changes to see if it starts to work. If it wasn't a code change, then something else happened on your computer that messed this up. I'm sorry, but there's really not much we can do to help you unless you remember what was done two weeks ago.

Comment: yeah, I figured it out. in the bin/rel folder, the libcurl.dll was missing. I manually copied it there and things started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was.

libcurl.dll was missing the bin/rel folder and hence CURL was throwing the error `CURLE_NOT_BUILT_IN`. I have manually copied the file to that folder and the application is working well